# Jmeter+Postman , jmeter isnt connecting with jmeter

Tags: jmeter, postman

Postman Collection that i run
isnt appearing in jmeter
i changed the proxy in postman and jmeter
but still im facing the same problem

Comment: Hello @Bader, What's error did you see in the Postman console?  Please ensure the JMeter proxy is started and the Postman proxy is properly configured.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 2):

1. Make sure to start the [HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP(S)_Test_Script_Recorder), you need to click the "Start" button

   [image]
2. If your Postman test is using [HTTPS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/https) protocol  - you will additionally need to [install JMeter's certificate into postman](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/certificates/)

   [image]

   the file is called `ApacheJMeterTemporaryRootCA.crt` and it's being generated in "bin" folder of your JMeter installation when you start the HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder
3. [Configure Postman to use JMeter as the proxy](https://learning.postman.com/docs/sending-requests/capturing-request-data/proxy/):

   [image]
4. Assuming all above steps are successfully implemented you should be able to record the Postman collection execution in JMeter. See [How to Convert Your Postman API Tests to JMeter for Scaling](https://www.blazemeter.com/how-to-convert-your-postman-api-tests-to-jmeter-for-scaling) article for more comprehensive instructions if needed

Answer (score 0):

- add ssl certificate
- configure the proxy
- if computer have something like special vpn or work vpn, close it